# Chi Square Test for Repeated Measures?

Tags: repeated-measures, chi-squared-test, choice-modeling

I have conducted a 3 alternative forced choice experiment (3AFC) where participants had to combine one out of three visualizations with a specific sound. There were 4 sets of different visualizations (a set consisted of 3 visualizations) and these sets were presented together with 3 different sounds. In other words, each sound was presented 4 times. There was a total of 4 sets x 3 sounds, i.e. 12 stimuli.

Considering that I presented every sound multiple times for each participant (but with different sets of visualizations), is it correct to run a chi-square test to analyze the association between the two variables "sounds" and "visualization"?

I am confused if this should be considered a repeated measures experiment since some of the sounds were presented several times. I am wondering if this could cause issues with the chi-square test, since this is a test that requires independence?